# reed strength for clarinet Vandoren M 13 mouthpiece

Tags: performing, clarinet

For the  fullest sounding tone, what read strength would be best recommended for the Vandoren M 13 clarinet mouthpiece

Answer (score 4):

Reed strength is more of a personal preference in terms of sound, but according to the Vandoren [website](http://www.vandoren.com/en/fprod/Becs%20de%20clarinette%20Sib%20en.pdf), they recommend anywhere from a 3 1/2 to a 5 in reed strength for that mouthpiece.